# How to set url of fonts in css file into mvc project?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I set url of fonts in css file such as this.

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'soap-icons';
  src: url("../fonts/soap-icons.eot?26664784");
  src: url("../fonts/soap-icons.eot?26664784#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/soap-icons.woff?26664784") format("woff"), url("../fonts/soap-icons.ttf?26664784") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/soap-icons.svg?26664784#soap-icons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

This run currently in html file.But after that I use this html file as a layout into mvc project It don't work currently .I test all css files path and found its are true.I change this urls to complete path of root site but don't work.
my project folders image :

[image]

Please advice

Comment: have you tried moving fonts to default fonts folder of application?

Comment: I move files into defoult fonts folder and solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this `src: url("/Content/Travelo/fonts/oap-icons.eot?26664784")`

**or**

try moving your fonts to default fonts folder of MVC application

Answer (score 0):

In your browser debug mode (`F12`), check in the network tag to see what the exact URL is that it is trying to retrieve your fonts from. It might be using a ../ too many.

Comment: Your mean is that I should remove (../ ) OK?

Comment: Check the url the browser is using. It might not be what you think it is.

It is best to retrieve resources, such as fonts and images, from the Content directory, like this: url('/Content/fonts/soap-icons.eot?26664784');